# Configuring GMail to use system email accounts

Tags: settings, email, gmail

Version 5 of GMail just arrived on my phone, and I was excited that now I'm able to use all my email addresses with it. But it seems like I have to add them all manually, although they are shown under Settings -> email and work just fine with the stock app.

Is there some way to use the already entered data in GMail 5? I'm afraid that in future versions it could rely on the system information and introduce some confusion where to change the settings, so I would like it to rely on the system settings from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I would do that not only for the Gmail app but all the Gmail. Go to your desktop pc, log into your account, go to settings and configure Gmail to receive all your emails inside your account.

Comment: If you meant that I should forward all my mail to GMail, you did not understand my question. Of course this would be a possibility, but I do not want to do that.